# Embed json in a class property

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jackson

I have 2 classes pretty similar with practicaly the same variables. The diferrence between them is one of them should have an ID and the other one shouldn't. I defined the next structure that contains all the info:

```
@JsonDeserialize (builder = ClassA.Builder.class)
@JsonInclude (Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class ClassA extends ParentClass {
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private Section section;

  private ClassA(Builder builder) {
    super(builder.version, builder.deleted, builder.given);
    this.section = builder.section;
  }

  public static Builder builder(ClassA copy) {
    Builder builder = new Builder();

    builder.section = copy.section;

    return builder;
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public Section getSection() {
    return section;
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private Section section;

    public Builder withSection(final Section section) {
      this.section = section;
      return this;
    }

    public ClassA build() {
      return new ClassA(this);
    }
  }
...
}

@JsonDeserialize (builder = Section.Builder.class)
@JsonInclude (Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Section {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Section> sections
    private List<String> availableBasis;
...
}
```

I tried to use @JsonUnwrapped but Resource is not mapping the json properly. This is the JSON that I'm using. I can deserialize pass object to JSON properly but not in the other way (from this JSON to the object):

```
{
  "id": "ClassAId",
  "name": "class A",
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": "section1",
      "name": "sectionName1"
    },
    {
      "id": "section2",
      "name": "sectionName2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wonder if I there is a way to let Jackson creating the correct structure in a @PostMapping without creating a custom parser. As I have to use the same in different parts of the application, writting my own parser is not a quick solution for it.

Thank you!

Comment: private List<Section> sections is not right.....a Section is supposed to contain a List<>.   Therefore I suggest you make another class, call it SimpleSection { id, name} , then your List<Section> becomes List<SimpleSection> and leave the rest the same..

Comment: thank you for your answer. You are right I can use id an name inside section. Indeed I forgot it, so I updated the question, thank you.  Basically I have a list of sections where section have all the info. But parent class is a single Section. I tried with the updated info and even it is not filling the correct info at all.

Comment: Please show the code for ClassA.Builder.class because that is what is used when deserializing

Comment: I added the code for ClassA.Builder. I created a test to check the output string and it is correct, but if I use the JSON I pasted in my question in POSTMAN it is not building anything at all:
  @Test
  void deleteMe() throws JsonProcessingException {
    var settings = ClassA.builder()
      .withSection(ClassA.Section.builder()
        .withId("abc")
        .withName("BABABA")
        .withAvailableBasis(List.of("CACCA"))
        .build())
      .build();

    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(settings));
  }

Comment: Hi Susan, I found the issue. I needed to add @JsonUnwrapped into the builder property. That's why it was serializing properly but not deserializing. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: I am glad you were able to fix it,